# Joining zig zag lines with regular lines to make a shape - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to turn this into a shape that will have one solid color as a fill, but object-> path -> join isn't working when I try to connect the final line (on the left) to complete the shape. Any thoughts? [image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting just two points at a time and joining them one set at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing the zig zag was created with the Effect?

You'll need to expand the effect first (`Object > Expand` and just tick the `Object` option).

Then you *may* need to `ungroup` the zig zags (`Object > Ungroup`).

Then you'll have just normal paths... which you can join easily.

---

Note the reason you need to expand the object is, failing to do so means the zig zag effect will *also* apply to any connected paths. So, if you want straight paths connected to zig zag paths, they have to be expanded first to "bake in" the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I see the path broken in 2 places on the left. 
The way to join them is:
Zoom way in to the endpoints you are trying to connect.
Move 1 endpoint directly onto or as close to the other as you can.
(You can move 1 endpoint with the white arrow tool)
Select both endpoints with the white arrow and hit Object/Path/Join.
In short, Illustrator won't join them if they aren't close enough.